# How to find specific rows start with certain letter in Snowflake

Tags: sql, sas

My input table:

| Customer | Records |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | YNNNYNYNNNNN |
| 0002 | NNNNNNYNNNNN |
| 0003 | YYNNYNYNYYNN |
| 0004 | NYNNYNYNNNNY |

The goal to find all rows with records start with letter Y as:

| Customer | Records |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | YNNNYNYNNNNN |
| 0003 | YYNNYNYNYYNN |

Comment: So many options. `left(), substring(), like`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that this has a SAS tag, so here are a few SAS solutions.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select *
        from snow.have
        where records LIKE 'Y%'
    ;
quit;
```

A data step will also work:

```
data want;
    set snow.have;
    where records =: 'Y';
run;
```

Or:

```
data want;
    set snow.have;
    where substr(records, 1, 1) = 'Y';
run;
```

Just check that your functions are compatible, or SAS will drag everything in the database to the SAS server before running the code. [Here is a list of supported SAS functions in Snowflake](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n1d5j8d7wegfezn1irjj3hcrne1n.htm).

To confirm that it's not doing this, use the following [sastrace options](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n0732u1mr57ycrn1urf24gzo38sc.htm):

```
options sastrace=',,,d' sastraceloc=saslog;
```

If you see the note below in the SAS log, then the function is not compatible. It will pass what it can to the DB, then do the rest.

```
ACCESS ENGINE: SQL statement was not passed to the DBMS, SAS will do the processing.
```

To avoid this entirely, you can also run SQL directly in Snowflake using the [SQL pass-through facility](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/p0t4fuigo1vzeun1bg9asejxrwl2.htm).

Answer (score 0):

One solution using %like is

```
SELECT *
 FROM TABLE 
WHERE Records LIKE 'Y_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _';
```

this solution only works when I know that all records have same length.

Comment: Why would you do that? Why not `records like 'Y%'`? Compare runtimes with other options such as `left(records, 1) = 'Y'` as well as `substring(records, 1, 1) = 'Y'`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a LIKE filter in the WHERE clause. You can find more information at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like

```
select * 
from <input table>
where records like 'Y%';
```